# In SAS, how to define table cell padding for tables with template styles using ODS tagsets.sasreport13?

Tags: templates, sas, sas-ods

I'm trying to define my template styles and I cannot increase the table cells padding when output is "ODS tagsets.sasreport13".

```
    style Table /
        cellpadding = 50pt          /* ONLY EFFECT HTML, PDF, RTF */
        ;
```

This code can change the table cells padding but only when output is HTML, PDF and RTF.

I have been trying with these too but they don't change anything

```
        paddingright = 50pt
        paddingtop = 50pt
        paddingright = 50pt
        paddingleft = 50pt
        padding = 50pt
```

HTML:
[image: HTML]

tagsets.sasreport13:
[image: tagsets.sasreport13]

**EDIT**:
Using SAS 9.3 and Enterprise Guide 7.1